# Escaping the Gravity well of the Moon

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, rocket-science, escape-velocity

How much energy would it take to get 1 kg from the Moon's surface to Earth? Would You aim for Lagrange Point 1 or would you launch in the opposite direction that the moon is orbiting?

Comment: Are you asking for a realistic estimate or a theoretical approach (difference of gravitational potential energies)?

Comment: I am sorry I don't know what the difference between a realistic estimate and theoretical approach.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_budget#Earth%E2%80%93Moon_space%E2%80%94high_thrust

Comment: *Theoretically* you have a net gain of energy if you transport a $1$ kg mass from the surface of the Moon to the surface of the Earth. In practice that gain in energy will be dissipated in heat, light and a loud inelastic collision.

Comment: @BowlOfRed The table is cool, but does not provide an answer to this question: It only gives $\delta v$ from moon to low earth orbit, which requires a braking burn to circularize the orbit. But, to go from the moon to the earth surface, one would definitely use aerobraking instead of firing rocket engines. I guess one should be able to find some answers in the calculations done for the Apollo moon missions, as they did return something from moon surface to the Pacific. You'd "just" need to remove the effects of the rendezvous in moon orbit (changed masses, deviation from direct route).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all bodies stationary the acceleration on the way from the earth to the moon is

$$ \rm g=\frac{G M_1}{r^2}-\frac{G M_2}{(d-r)^2} $$

where $\rm M_1$ and $\rm M_2$ is the mass of earth and moon and $\rm d$ the distance from the center of the earth to the center of the moon. At the radius

$$ \rm R_0 = \frac{d M_1-d \sqrt{M_1} \sqrt{M_2}}{M_1-M_2} $$

the acceleration in the direction of the earth and that in the direction of the moon cancel each other out, so the specific kinetic energy to get that far is

$$ \rm e=\int_{R_1}^{R_0} g \, dr $$

where $\rm R_1$ ist the radius of the earth. Assuming vacuum the initial velocity needed would be

$$ \rm v_0=\frac{c \sqrt{e} \sqrt{2 c^2+e}}{c^2+e} $$

which is a little bit lower than the escape velocity to infinity. Under ideal circumstances you would need

$$ \rm 6.13*10^7 \ J/kg $$

of energy in joule per kilogram of your cargo to make it from the surface of the earth to $\rm R_0$, and from there you gain

$$ \rm 2.58*10^6 \ J/kg $$

kinetic energy with which you will hit the surface of the moon (integrate from $\rm R_0$ to $\rm d-R_2$ where the latter is the radius of the moon). If you want to land softly, you will have to use that amount to decelerate again. If you start on the moon and want to land on the earth it is simply the other way around.

Comment: Why are all your variables upright?

Answer (score -1):

Approximation:

The formula for escape velocity is:

$Vesc =  \sqrt (\frac{2∗G∗M}{r})$

Where:

G = 6.67384E-11 N*m^2*kg^-2 (Gravitational Constant)

M = 7.34767E22 kg (mass of the moon)

r = 1737400 m (radius of the moon)

Plug those in and we get an escape velocity of 2375.89 m/s

To reach this speed the kinetic energy required is $Ke = \frac{1}{2} mv^2$

or   $\frac{1}{2} * 1kg * 2375.89 m/s * 2375.89 m/s $= **2,822,426joule**

L1 seems reasonable, but I'm no expert. You'd probably want to consider the 4.627 m/s rotation velocity the moon has. You'll come off in a tangent.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is the formula to totally escape the pull of the Moon. I was thinking that the escape velocity isn't quite the same as the velocity needed to get from the moon to the earth. You only need to get a few million meters from the moon before you begin falling to the Earth.

Comment: You must escape the gravity well of the moon first. Then you will automatically be in the gravity well of the earth.  Think of it like a hole dug on the side of a hill first you must get out of the hole then you'll roll down the hill.

Comment: You don't need to totally escape the pull of the moon though. You only need to get a little bit past the first Lagrange Point before you begin to fall away from the moon. That distance is only 5.8 million meters to the moon's surface.

Comment: Agreed, in the best case scenario. Which is why mine 'answer' is a simple approximation.

Comment: Math error: the answer is 1/2*1*(2375^2) = 2.82 million J